# SCNScene: Calculate projected size of an object

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

My game has a scene and HUD (SKScene) as in most games. To avoid overlap with HUD elements, I need to calculate the projected size of my main object. Because the HUD dimensions and projected size of the object are different for each iPhone model, I need a way to do this dynamically, and for that I need to get the projected size of my main object.

The obvious approach for me was to use the xFov and yFov, but for some reason they are always zero. `usesOrthographicProjection` is set to false so it's not because of that.

Below a simple test code that trys to equal the plane of the scene with the plane on the HUD.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var hud:SKScene!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene()

        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 10)

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = self.view as SCNView

        // set the scene to the view
        scnView.scene = scene

        let sCPlaneGeo = SCNPlane(width: 5, height: 5)
        let sCPlane = SCNNode(geometry: sCPlaneGeo)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sCPlane)

        hud = SKScene(size: view.bounds.size)
        scnView.overlaySKScene = hud


        let sKplane = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSizeMake(50, 50))
        sKplane.lineWidth = 1
        sKplane.position = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width/2, view.bounds.size.height/2)
        sKplane.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()

        hud.addChild(sKplane)

        println(cameraNode.camera?.xFov) //Prints Zero

    }

}
```

Comment: Found out that Fov is 60 degrees if xFov or yFov are not changed.
Still, don't know how to transform from points to pixels.
Also would like to know why i got a negative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Use `getBoundingBoxMin(_:max:)` to find the corners of the space your 3D element occupies in the SceneKit scene.
2. Use `projectPoint` to convert those points from 3D scene coordinates to 2D view coordinates.
3. Use `convertPointFromView` to convert from (UIKit) view coordinates to your SpriteKit scene's coordinate system.

From the points in step 3 you can construct a rectangle or other shape for your HUD elements to avoid.

Comment: i was far away from finding the solution.