# Get frame of SceneKit node in app window?

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, scenekit, scnnode

I'm hoping to overlay a UIView (specifically a highlight box with some text, etc) over an object rendered in SceneKit, but I'm encountering an issue: I don't know exactly where the object will be onscreen at the time.

Is there a way to get the CGRect frame of a SCNNode's current position within the SCNView? Even just a center point for the node would be helpful, but ideally it would give the whole frame, indicating how much vertical and horizontal space the geometry was taking up onscreen as well.

I've searched in the documentation and online for various references to "frames" and "bounds" relative to an SCNNode, but all I'm finding is stuff about the coordinate system within the scene.

Is there no way of translating a SCNNode's position in a scene into the frame coordinates of the view, or the app window?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696847/scnscene-calculate-projected-size-of-an-object

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the post about [calculating the projected size of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696847/scnscene-calculate-projected-size-of-an-object).
2. Performance wise, it is much better to use SpriteKit in SceneKit if you want to overlay 2D contents. Check the [overlaySKScene](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1524051-overlayskscene) property of SCNSceneRenderer.